# How can I install the sample AdventureWorksDW database on SQL DW using an ARM script

Tags: azure-synapse

I can create a SQL DW using ARM no problem. However, the portal supports an option of also installing a sample database - e.g. AdventureWorksDW. How can I do the equivalent using an ARM script?

BTW, I clicked on "automation options" on the portal add it shows an ARM script with an extension that probably is the piece that installs the sample database, but it asks for some parameters (e.g. `storageKey`, `storageUri`) that I don't know.

Here's what I think is the relevant portion of the ARM JSON:

```
"name": "PolybaseImport",
"type": "extensions",
"apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
"dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/databases/', parameters('databaseName'))]"
],
"properties": {
    "storageKeyType": "[parameters('storageKeyType')]",
    "storageKey": "[parameters('storageKey')]",
    "storageUri": "[parameters('storageUri')]",
    "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
    "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]",
    "operationMode": "PolybaseImport"
}
```

More specifically, looking at the ARM deploy script generated from the portal, here are the key elements that I need to know in order to auto deploy using my own ARM script:

```
…
    "storageKey": {
        "value": null  <- without knowing this, I can’t deploy.
    },
    "storageKeyType": {
        "value": "SharedAccessKey"
    },
    "storageUri": {
        "value": https://sqldwsamplesdefault.blob.core.windows.net/adventureworksdw/AdventureWorksDWPolybaseImport/Manifest.xml  <- this is not a public blob, so can’t look at it
    },
…
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK that's currently not possible. The portal kicks off a workflow that provisions the new DW resources, generates the sample DW schema then loads data. The sample is stored in a non-public blob so you won't be able to access it.

I don't think it's hard to make it available publicly but it does take some work so perhaps you should add a suggestion here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse